# Will private APIs rejected in review?

Tags: ios, api, itunes

I want to develop an API which will help developers to do a particular job and helps them to build specific app. It will include my own ads. However, I'm not sure If Apple will accept this? Is this kind of APIs called private APIs? I know some examples in Android.

Comment: No, private API are API that are non public iOS APIs. So any API you want to call that is not listed in the API reference for iOS.

Comment: So can I do something like this for iOS? http://www.ytsdk.com

Comment: Yes you could. You might get run into a problem by allowing download of Youtube movies since this is not allowed by Youtube.

Comment: theoretically yes, it is not a private api, you still might not be allowed to do exactly that because that might conflict with youtube tos etc or some other apple review guidelines, but that has nothing to do with the term "private api".

Comment: What will Apple look in third party API? I mean it will be bunch of codes and If I write them in main, not in API. It probably be accepted. So doing things in API will change it?